# How to perform same action regardless of promise fulfilment?

Tags: javascript, promise, winjs

I would like to perform the same action after a promise has either been fulfilled with a success result or failure, ie I want to perform the same action for the success and error handler and then continue to send down the result of the promise to the appropriate erroe/success handlers.

```
var pleaseWaitPromise = playAudioAsync("please wait");

myLongRunningPromise().then(function tempSuccessHandler(result) {
  pleaseWaitPromise.cancel();
  return result;
}, function tempErrorHandler(error) {
  pleaseWaitPromise.cancel();
  return WinJS.Promise.wrapError(error);
}).done(function realSuccessHandler(result) {
  console.info(result);
}, function realError(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Is there a more elegant way to stop the `pleaseWaitPromise`, which could also be a function call instead of a promise (like `clearInterval`)

Comment: You don't say what Promise library you are using, but with the Bluebird promise library, you can use `.finally()` for actions that you want to run no matter how the promise was fulfilled. See [here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#finallyfunction-handler---promise) for details.

Comment: as described by the tags I thought it was clear, WinJS. `Finally` looks like it can only be at the end of the promise chain. I want it be in the middle of the chain.

Comment: For those of us who don't know winJS, it's not clear to me that it has it's own promise library (even after I looked it up on the web).  If you want help from the larger community, it's better to be more specific in your question.   All the non-standard methods like `.finally()` are library-specific so you will have to see what winJS has in this regard.

Comment: I try to be more specific in the question next time.

Answer (score 1):

jfriend is right you'd typically want `finally` here - it does exactly what your code above does. Sadly WinJS promises do not feature `.finally` at the moment so unless you'd like to shim it (patching it on the prototype of WinJS.promise) you're stuck with it.

You can also put it as a function:

```
function always(prom, fn){
     return prom.then(function(v){ fn(v); return v; },
                      function(e){ fn(e); return WinJS.Promise.wrapError(error); });
}
```

Which would look like:

```
always(myLongRunningPromise(),
  pleaseWaitPromise.cancel();
})).done(function realSuccessHandler(result) {
  console.info(result);
}, function realError(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Yes, a monkey-patch like `WinJS.Promise.always` would be nice to have. I try to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I don't understand the extra step, wouldn't this just do what you want?

```
var pleaseWaitPromise = playAudioAsync("please wait");

myLongRunningPromise().then(function tempSuccessHandler(result) {
  pleaseWaitPromise.cancel();
  console.info(result);
}, function tempErrorHandler(error) {
  pleaseWaitPromise.cancel();
  console.error(error);
});
```

*edit*: second try

I know it is a known anti-pattern, but what if you return a Promise that never fails? Something like:

```
function neverFails(myLongRunningPromise, pleaseWaitPromise){
    return new WinJS.Promise(function (complete){
        myLongRunningPromise().then(function () {
            pleaseWaitPromise.cancel();
            console.info(result);
            return complete();
        }, function (error) {
            pleaseWaitPromise.cancel();
            console.error(error);
            return complete();
         });
     });
}
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: In that simple case yes. But my promise chain is much more complicated. So I need an early stop of the audio output. Something like `finally` as suggested by @BenjaminGruenbaum, but more like `first` that is called before any other continuation handler.

Comment: Added a new scenario, let me know if it helps (or doesn't)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. It seems like this could work *if* the error handler also re-throws the error condition (or a modified one). I just don't like the calling convention imposed by this solution. I've filed an issue to the WinJS git repo, maybe those guys have a clever idea. Thanks again!