# Run secondary action after promise regardless of outcome?

Tags: javascript, redux, promise, progressive-web-apps, thunk

I found this previous thread ([How to perform same action regardless of promise fulfilment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320139/how-to-perform-same-action-regardless-of-promise-fulfilment)), but it's 5 years old and references winjs is a kludge.

What I would like to do is load a list of data elements.  I've got local copies of the list and local copies of the elements -- but they may have changed on the server side.

That process should work like this:  load the LIST from the database into the local storage (Comparing against the local) --> THEN load the (multiple) DATA ELEMENTS from the database that are listed in the LIST.

So if the "loadList" async function succeeds... I want to run the "loadElements" async function.  If the loadList function rejects... I STILL want to run the "loadElements" function (Which fires off multiple fetch requests - one for each element).

"Use 'finally'" I hear you say...  but I want to pass the results of the "loadList" resolve/reject and "loadElements" resolve/reject functions to the calling function.  'finally' doesn't receive or pass properties as far as I know.

The reason I want to pass the results to the calling function is to see if the rejection reasons are acceptable reasons and I can trust the local copy as the authoritative copy or not (for example, if the DB doesn't contain the LIST, I can trust that the local list is the authoritative version)... so I need a way to analyze the 'failures' within the calling function.

Here is what I have:

```
export function syncLinkTablesAndElementsWithDB(username) { 
return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            dispatch(loadLinkTableAndElementsFromDB(STATIONS_LINK_TABLE_TYPE, username))
                .then((msg) => {
                    console.log("loadLinkTableAndElementsFromDB RESOLVED: ", msg);
                    resolve(msg)

                })
                .then(() => {
                    dispatch(pushLinkTableToDB(STATIONS_LINK_TABLE_TYPE, username))
                    dispatch(pushAllUserStationsToDB(username))
                 })
                .catch((allPromReasons) => {
                    console.log("loadLinkTableAndElementsFromDB REJECTED: ", allPromReasons);
                    allReasonsAcceptable = true;
                    allPromReasons.forEach(reason => {
                        if (!isAcceptableLoadFailureReasonToOverwrite(reason)) {
                            allReasonsAcceptable = false;
                        }
                    });
                    if (allReasonsAcceptable) {
                        //TODO:   DO push of local to DB
                        // eventually return results of the push to DB...

                    } else {
                        reject(allPromReasons)
                    }
                })
        });
    }
}


export function loadLinkTableAndElementsFromDB(tableType, username) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            dispatch(loadLinkTableFromDB(tableType, username))
                .then(successMsg => {
                    resolve(Promise.all([successMsg, dispatch(loadAllUsersStationsFromDB(username)).catch(err=>err)]))
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    reject(Promise.all([err, dispatch(loadAllUsersStationsFromDB(username)).catch(err=>err)]))
                })
        });
    }
}

export function loadAllUsersStationsFromDB(username) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let linkTable = getStationsLinkTable(username); // get the local link table
            if (linkTable && Array.isArray(linkTable.stations)) { // if there is a local station list
                let loadPromises = linkTable.stations.map(stationID => dispatch(loadStationFromDB(stationID)).catch((err) => err));
                Promise.all(loadPromises)
                    .then((allReasons) => {
                        let allSuccesses = true;
                        allReasons.forEach(reason => {
                            if (!reason.startsWith(SUCCESS_RESPONSE)) {
                                allSuccesses = false;
                            }
                        });
                        if (allSuccesses) {
                            resolve(SUCCESS_RESPONSE + ": " + username);
                        } else {
                            reject(allReasons);
                        }
                    })
            } else {
                return reject(NO_LINK_TABLE_AVAILABLE + ": " + username);
            }
        });
    };
}
```

loadStationFromDB and loadLinkTableFromDB do what you'd expect... try to load those things from from the DB.  I can include their code if you think it's worthwhile.

-----------  EDIT  -----------
To clarify what I'm trying to accomplish:

I'm trying to sync local storage with a database.  I want to do this by pulling the data from the database, compare the time/datestamps.  This will make the local storage version the authoritative copy of all the data.  After the loads from the DB, I'd like to then push the local storage version up to the DB.

I need to care for the fact that the database will often simply not have the data at all, and thus might 'reject' on a pull... even though, in the instance of a sync, that rejection is acceptable and should not stop the sync process.

Per suggestions below, I've modified my code:

```
export function loadLinkTableAndElementsFromDB(tableType, username) {
    console.log("loadLinkTableAndElementsFromDB(", tableType, username, ")");
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            dispatch(loadLinkTableFromDB(tableType, username))
                .then(successMsg => {
                    console.log("loadLinkTableFromDB RESOLVED: ", successMsg)
                    resolve(Promise.all([successMsg, dispatch(loadAllUsersStationsFromDB(username)).catch(err => err)]))
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log("loadLinkTableFromDB REJECTED: ", err)
                    reject(Promise.all([err, dispatch(loadAllUsersStationsFromDB(username)).catch(err => err)]))
                })
        });
    }
}

export function syncLinkTablesAndElementsWithDB(username) {
    console.log("syncLinkTablesAndElementsWithDB(", username, ")");
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(loadLinkTableFromDB(STATIONS_LINK_TABLE_TYPE, username))
            .then((successLoadLinkTableMsg) => {
                console.log('Successfully loaded link table: ', successLoadLinkTableMsg)
                return dispatch(pushLinkTableToDB(STATIONS_LINK_TABLE_TYPE, username))
            })
            .catch((rejectLoadLinkTableReason) => {
                console.log("Failed to load link table from DB: " + rejectLoadLinkTableReason);
                if (allReasonsAcceptableForOverwrite(rejectLoadLinkTableReason)) {  // some rejection reasons are accectable... so if failed reason is okay.... 
                    console.log("Failure to load link table reasons were acceptable... pushing local link table anyway");
                    return dispatch(pushLinkTableToDB(STATIONS_LINK_TABLE_TYPE, username))
                } else {
                    console.log("Throwing: ", rejectLoadLinkTableReason);
                    throw rejectLoadLinkTableReason;
                }
            })  
            .then((successPushLinkTaleMsg) => { 
                console.log("Successfully pushed link table: " + successPushLinkTaleMsg);
                return dispatch(loadAllUsersStationsFromDB(username)); // I want this to occur regardless of if the link table stuff succeeds or fails...  but it must occur AFTER the loadLinkTableFromDB at least tries...
            })
            .catch((rejectPushLinkTableReason) => {
                console.log("Failed to push link table: " + rejectPushLinkTableReason);
                return dispatch(loadAllUsersStationsFromDB(username)); // I want this to occur regardless of if the link table stuff succeeds or fails...  but it must occur AFTER the loadLinkTableFromDB at least tries... 
            })
            .then((successLoadAllUserStationsMsg) => {
                console.log("Successfully loaded all user stations: " + successLoadAllUserStationsMsg);
                return dispatch(pushAllUserStationsToDB(username))
            })
            .catch((rejectLoadAllUserStationsReason) => {
                console.log("Failed to push all users stations: " + rejectLoadAllUserStationsReason);
                if (allReasonsAcceptableForOverwrite(rejectLoadAllUserStationsReason)) {  // some rejection reasons are accectable... so if failed reason is okay.... 
                    console.log("Load users stations reasons are acceptable...");
                    return dispatch(pushAllUserStationsToDB(username))
                } else {
                    console.log("throwing: ", rejectLoadAllUserStationsReason);
                    throw rejectLoadAllUserStationsReason;
                }
            })
            .then((successPushAllUserStationsMgs) => {
                console.log("Successfully pushed all users stations: " + successPushAllUserStationsMgs);
                return Promise.resolve();
            })
            .catch((rejectPushAllUserStationsReason) => {
                console.log("Failed to push all users stations: " + rejectPushAllUserStationsReason);
                throw rejectPushAllUserStationsReason;
            })
    };
}


export function syncAllWithDB(username) { 
    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        // other stuff will occur here...

            dispatch(syncLinkTablesAndElementsWithDB(username))  // *** Error here ***
                .then((successMsg) => {
                    console.log("Successful sync for : " + successMsg);
                })
                .catch(allReasons => {
                    console.warn("Link tables and elements sync error: ", allReasons);
                })
        // });
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm now getting getting 'TypeError: dispatch(...) is undefined' on the dispatch in the syncAllWithDB function.    This function hasn't changed...

Comment: First get rid of the anti-pattern where you're wrapping a promise in another manually created promise.  No need for that.  Just return the promise you already have.

Comment: Where?  I don't follow...

Comment: Remove `new Promise()` from your code.  Just use and return the promises you already have.  That will chain them together.  If you don't understand this, then read about "chaining" promises.

Comment: If I remove line 3 from the above code (the first 'new Promise'...) and line 11 (the corresponding bracket and parenthesis) it doesn't compile... saying resolve and reject are not defined.  Replacing reject and resolve with 'return' results in errors in the calling function (which is expecting a promise to call reject/resolve.   (the error is dispatch not found)

Comment: You remove the resolve/reject too.  You `return` new promises from within `.then()` handlers to chain them together.  Go read about "chaining" promises and "promise anti-patterns".  I'm not on a computer I can type lots more than that right now.

Comment: I don't want to always just pass the reject/resolve on through, though... I want to check what was in the resolve/reject and pass on a resolve/reject depending on what came in.  (ie: if the reasons for rejection were acceptable, I want to pass on a resolve rather than a reject)

Answer (score 1):

I don't entirely follow what you're trying to accomplish (more on that below), but the first thing to do here is to clean up the flow and not wrap an extra `new Promise()` around existing promises.  There is never a reason to do this:

```
 function someFunc() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           callSomething.then(result => {
               ...
               doSomethingElse(result).then(result2 => {
                    ...
                    resolve(result2);
               }).catch(err => {
                    ...
                    reject(err);
               });
           }).catch(err => {
               ...
               reject(err);
           });
      });
 }
```

That is a well-known promise anti-pattern.  You don't need the extra manually created promise wrapped around your function that already makes a promise.  Instead, you can just return the promise you already have.  This is called "promise chaining".  From within the chain you can reject or resolve the chain from anywhere.

```
 function someFunc() {
     return callSomething.then(result => {
         ...
         // return promise here, chaining this new async operation 
         // to the previous promise
         return doSomethingElse(result).then(result2 => {
              ...
              return result2;
         }).catch(err => {
              ...
              // after doing some processing on the error, rethrow
              // to keep the promise chain rejected
              throw err;
         });
    }).catch(err => {
         ...
         reject err;
    });
 }
```

Or, you can even flatten the promise chain like this:

```
 function someFunc() {
     return callSomething.then(result => {
         ...
         return doSomethingElse(result);
     }).then(result2 => {
         ...
         return result2;
    }).catch(err => {
         ...
         throw err;
    });
 }
```

As an example of that, you can simplify `syncLinkTablesAndElementsWithDB()` like this:

```
export function syncLinkTablesAndElementsWithDB(username) { 
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return dispatch(loadLinkTableAndElementsFromDB(STATIONS_LINK_TABLE_TYPE, username)).then((msg) => {
            console.log("loadLinkTableAndElementsFromDB RESOLVED: ", msg);
            dispatch(pushLinkTableToDB(STATIONS_LINK_TABLE_TYPE, username))
            dispatch(pushAllUserStationsToDB(username))
            // have msg be the resolved value of the promise chain
            return(msg);
        }).catch((allPromReasons) => {
            console.log("loadLinkTableAndElementsFromDB REJECTED: ", allPromReasons);
            let allReasonsAcceptable = allPromReasons.every(reason => {
                return isAcceptableLoadFailureReasonToOverwrite(reason);
            });
            if (allReasonsAcceptable) {
                //TODO:   DO push of local to DB
                // eventually return results of the push to DB...
            } else {
                // have promise stay rejected
                throw allPromReasons;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As for the rest of your question, you're asking this:

> So if the "loadList" async function succeeds... I want to run the "loadElements" async function. If the loadList function rejects... I STILL want to run the "loadElements" function (Which fires off multiple fetch requests - one for each element).

But, there are not functions in your code called `loadList()` and `loadElements()` so you lost me there so I'm not sure how to make a specific code suggestion.

Inside a `.then()` handler in a promise chain, you can do three things:

1. **Return a value.**  That value becomes the resolved value of the promise chain.
2. **Return a promise.**  That promise is attached to the promise chain and the whole promise chain (the top-most promise that a caller would be watching) will eventually resolve/reject when this promise you are returning resolves/rejects (or anything that is also chained onto it resolves/rejects).
3. **Throw an exception.**  All `.then()` handlers are automatically watched for exceptions and if any exception is throw, then the promise chain is automatically rejected with the exception value set as the reject reason.

So, that gives you the ultimate flexibility to finish the promise chain with a value or an error or to link it to another promise (more asynchronous operations).

Comment: Sorry, the 'loadList' is 'loadLinkTable' and 'loadElement' is 'loadStationFromDB'...

Comment: @lowcrawler - Please edit your question to refer to the actual functions you want to call and clarify  what you're trying to do.  I still don't understand what you're trying to accomplish or what the problem is with your current code.

Comment: When I use a 'throw' instead of a 'reject', then I get uncaught exceptions and TypeError: dispatch(...) is undefined errors...

Comment: @lowcrawler - I can only help with specific code that shows a specific problem.   I can't guess what code you tried.  A `throw` inside a `.then()` handler will just cause the promise to reject, nothing more.

Comment: @lowcrawler - If `syncAllWithDB` is telling you that `dispatch` is undefined, then you must not be using it correctly because, as you can see, `dispatch` is supposed to be passed into it.  You don't show where it's being used so nothing I can do to help there.  You still haven't edited the original question to explain what functions you're trying to call where.

Comment: I'm just calling it from a button.  I added that to the original question.  Nothing changed in that button, or the syncAllWithDB... the only changes were in the syncLinkTablesAndElementsWithDB function.  I'm still calling `syncAllWithDB` the exact same way.
I'm not sure what extra info would be helpful.  I'm so thankful for your assistance, just let me know what you need to help point me in the right direction....

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're trying to do.  I'll have to leave this for someone else to try to understand.